# dispatch inside of child useEffect causes infinite rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

**App.js**

```js
return (
    <Router history={createBrowserHistory}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />

        <Route
          path="/login"
          element={
            <LoginAuth redirectTo="/dashboard">
              <SignIn set_token={setAuthToken} setUserType={setUserType} />
            </LoginAuth>
          }
        />

        <Route path="/register" element={<SignUp />} />

        <Route
          path="/dashboard/*"
          element={
            <RequireAuth redirectTo="/login">
              <UserDashboard />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />

        <Route path="/register/subscription" element={<Package />} />

        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />

        <Route path="/pricing" element={<Pricing />} />

        <Route path="/features" element={<Features />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
```

**UserDashboard.js**
when route is 'localhost../dashboard' it renders this component and in this useeffect I append URL with home so that home component render automatically.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    history("home");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="dash-cont background-blue">
      <header className="head-cont">
        <div className="top-left-head">
          <div className="left-header">
            <a href="/" className="b-brand">
              <span className="logo">SchoolSavvy</span>
            </a>

            <a href="#!" className="mob-toggler" onClick={onToggle}>
              <Hamburger
                className="hamburger-react"
                toggled={isOpen}
                toggle={setOpen}
              />
            </a>

            <div className="right_head_popup">
              <MoreVertIcon />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="right-header">
            <NotificationsNoneOutlinedIcon className="notify-ico" />
            <PersonOutlineOutlinedIcon className="person-ico" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div className="body-div">
        <UserSidebar is_Open={isOpen} on_Toggle={onToggle} />

        <div className="dash-info">
          {/* Heading */}
          <PathHeading />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/school/*" element={<SchoolComp />} />
            <Route path="/student/*" element={<></>} />
            <Route path="/parent/*" element={<></>} />
            <Route path="/teacher/*" element={<></>} />
            <Route path="/class/*" element={<></>} />
            <Route path="/exam/*" element={<></>} />
            <Route path="/attendance/*" element={<></>} />
            <Route path="/timetable/*" element={<></>} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

**Home.js**
when this component is rendered, dispatch in useEffect causes infinite rendering, anyone knows what's the problem? Thanks

```js
const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("home rend");
    dispatch(loadDashboard());
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {/* Cards */}
      <Card />

      <div className="sch_summary">
        {/* Charts */}
        <BarChart />

        <NoticeBoard />
      </div>
      <Calendar />
    </>
  );
};
```

**Here is loadDashboard action which is dispatched by useEffect**

```js
export const loadDashboard = () => async (dispatch, getstate) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: actionType.DASHBOARD_REQ,
    });

    console.log(`tokennn: ${getstate().user.token}`);
    
    const { data } = await axios.get("/v1/user/dashboard/detail", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${getstate().user.token}`,
      },
    });

    dispatch({
      type: actionType.DASHBOARD_SUCCESS,
      payload: data.user,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`falii: ${error}`);

    dispatch({
      type: actionType.DASHBOARD_FAILURE,
      payload: error.response.data,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Add `dispatch` as dependency in the array u attached to useEffect.

Comment: I have done this before but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add the dispatch actions that cause infinite rerender to `ref` using `useRef`.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

function useAddFnToRef(fn) {
  const refProps = useRef({ fn });
  return refProps.current.fn;
}

const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onLoadDashboard = useAddFnToRef(()=>dispatch(loadDashboard()))
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("home rend");
    onLoadDashboard();
  }, [onLoadDashboard]);

  return (
    <>
      {/* Cards */}
      <Card />

      <div className="sch_summary">
        {/* Charts */}
        <BarChart />

        <NoticeBoard />
      </div>
      <Calendar />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I tried but, its not working

Comment: Can you make a sandbox on Codesandbox?

Comment: What was the error exactly? I am using the custom hook in many of my projects. Working fine.

Comment: Not showing any error, just infinite rendering  in effect if I do dispatch any action

Comment: sure! this is sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/live/4084dbf2735

Comment: it says "It seems like this session doesn't exist or has been closed". Please share the link to your sandbox not live session one.

Comment: oh, I share that link mistakenly.
here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/zillay-abbas-schoolsavvy-6bc1fb
it's forked from the github repo